# Modify selection, select word and then reattach the caret position

Tags: javascript, selection, wysiwyg

So i'm trying to make a wysiwyg editor in javascript. What i'm trying to do is: when I havent made a selection and only stand with the caret on a word, I want to select the word, execute a command on it and then move the caret back to its position.

Example: 
Before I execute my code (the caret should be here after my function):

make this word b|old

After:

make this word **bold**|

jsFiddle Example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v4srtvsL/11/)

My code so far:

```
    if (window.getSelection && (sel = window.getSelection()).modify) {
        doc.focus(); // the editor
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        var oldRange = document.createRange();
        oldRange.setStart(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
        oldRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);

        sel.collapseToStart();           

        sel.modify("move", "forward", "character");
        sel.modify("move", "backward", "word");
        sel.modify("extend", "forward", "word");

        document.execCommand(command, false, value);

        // Restore selection, Dosen't work as I expected
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(oldRange);
}
```

Comment: Are you having a problem with that code? It would help if you could include a description in your post.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear, added a jsFiddle that show's my problem. I'm using firefox if that matters

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that right after you run `document.execCommand`, it resets the range, you can do a console.log on `oldRange` and comment out the `document.execCommand` line to confirm. The only way to save the old range is to serialize it, like I've done in the example below. Take a look

#### Solution

```js
changeStyle = function(command) {
    var sel;  
    var doc = document.getElementById('editor');

    if (window.getSelection && (sel = window.getSelection()).modify) {
      doc.focus();
      var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      var oldRange = saveCaret(doc);
    
      sel.collapseToStart();
    
      sel.modify("move", "forward", "character");
      sel.modify("move", "backward", "word");
      sel.modify("extend", "forward", "word");
    
      document.execCommand(command, false, null);
    
      // Restore selection, well, it isn't restoring it
      restoreCaret(doc, oldRange)
    }
}
saveCaret = function(container) {
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var preSelectionRange = range.cloneRange();
  preSelectionRange.selectNodeContents(container);
  preSelectionRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
  var start = preSelectionRange.toString().length;

  return {
    start: start,
    end: start + range.toString().length
  };
};
restoreCaret = function(container, position) {
  var charIndex = 0, range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(container, 0);
  range.collapse(true);
  var nodeStack = [container], node, foundStart = false, stop = false;

  while (!stop && (node = nodeStack.pop())) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
      var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
      if (!foundStart && position.start >= charIndex && position.start <= nextCharIndex) {
        range.setStart(node, position.start - charIndex);
        foundStart = true;
      }
      if (foundStart && position.end >= charIndex && position.end <= nextCharIndex) {
        range.setEnd(node, position.end - charIndex);
        stop = true;
      }
      charIndex = nextCharIndex;
    } else {
      var i = node.childNodes.length;
      while (i--) {
        nodeStack.push(node.childNodes[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  var sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeStyle('bold')">
  Bold
</button>
<div contentEditable=true id="editor">
Try make a word bold without make a selection, the caret will either jump to the start of the word or the end.
It should stay on its position.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone whoever may stumble upon this issue in the future, the implementation isn't so straightforward - mainly due to the difficulty of tracking and manipulating the caret. Also, cross-browser line-endings are a cause for problem in any attempted implementation.

However, [jquery.caret](https://github.com/acdvorak/jquery.caret) does a pretty good job of enabling caret information and manipulation, so consider checking it out.